# Angular 2 - Property is undefined after subscription ended

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, frontend, observable

Using angular 2+ - I have declared a public property which I am expecting to be populated with promise data object, using "ngOnInit" lifecycle method in order to send http request to my API.

in subscribe block I am assigning the property to the data received from the observable but then I want to log this property its appear as undefined outside the subscription but not undefined inside the subscription block which is odd behavior (am i missing something?) code below:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<any> {
  console.log(this.indexID);
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-wrap');
  while (elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
  }
  await this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID)
  .subscribe((res:any) => {
    this.landingData = res['data'][0];    
  });
  console.log(this.landingData); 
}
```

Comment: Does the landing data variable exist as part of a class member?

Comment: `await this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID).subscribe((res:any) => { this.landingData = res['data'][0]; });` doesn't make sense. `.subscribe` returns a subscription. You can't await it. You can't await an observable, because it can trigger multiple times, but you can convert an observable to a promise, e.g. with [firstValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom)

Comment: ive tried the way w/o async await but yet propety wont populate so my template cannot read undefined, 
yes the data varible is part of the class

Comment: _"its appear as undefined outside the subscription but not undefined inside the subscription block which is odd behavior"_ That's not odd. That's the expected behavior. `this.landingData = res['data'][0];` is executed after `console.log(this.landingData);`. `this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID)` returns an asynchronous observable.

Comment: ive converted it into an promise now its work

Answer (score 0):

```
await this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID)
.subscribe((res:any) => {
  this.landingData = res['data'][0];    
});
```

doesn't make sense. `.subscribe` returns a subscription. You can't await it. You can't await an observable, because it can trigger multiple times, but you can convert an observable to a promise, e.g. with [`firstValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom)

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  console.log(this.indexID);
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-wrap');
  while (elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
  }
  const res = await firstValueFrom(this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID));
  this.landingData = res['data'][0];    
  console.log(this.landingData); 
}
```

> its appear as undefined outside the subscription but not undefined inside the subscription block which is odd behavior

That's not odd. That's the expected behavior. `this.landingData = res['data'][0];` is executed after `console.log(this.landingData);`. `this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID)` returns an asynchronous observable. You can remove `async` / `await` and move the `console.log` into the observer:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.indexID);
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-wrap');
  while (elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
  }
  this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID)
  .subscribe((res:any) => {
    this.landingData = res['data'][0];  
    console.log(this.landingData);   
  });
}
```

Comment: i did it that way before the async attempt, it still doesnt work the way you suggest for some reason

Comment: @YarinMaimon _"It still doesn't work"_ isn't a useful problem description.

Comment: check out my last answer

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is asynchronous functions which means that TypeScript won’t wait for a function to finish before executing the code below it. In below code, First execute the 2nd log and then execute 1st log. so you will not get the return data in log

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<any> {
   await this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID)
  .subscribe((res:any) => {
    this.landingData = res['data'][0];   
  console.log('data'); 
  });
  console.log(this.landingData); 
}
```

Try this it will work

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.landingService.getLandingDataById(this.indexID)
  .subscribe((res:any) => {
    this.landingData = res['data'][0];  
    console.log(this.landingData);   
  });
}
```